# Xcodeがios Simulator起動時に「xcodeが予期しない理由で終了しました」

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode Version 6.3.1 (6D1002)にアップデート後、新たにプロジェクトを作成し、command+Rでビルドランを実行すると「xcodeが予期しない理由で終了しました」というダイアログが表示され、Xcodeが落ちてしまいます。対処法を教えて下さい。

OSはYosemite 10.10です。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: iOS simulatorのバージョンはいくつですか？最新のものにしてもダメでしょうか？

Comment: @tutinoco 回答有難うございます。simulatorはVersion 8.3で最新です。ログなどを確認したいのですが、どこに生成されるのかわかりますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcodeが予期しない理由で終了しました。というのは、デベロッパーなら、みたことはない、と言う人はいないほど、出るケースですが。100発100中で再現するなら、

1. Activity Monitorで、走行中のXcode, iOS simulatorがないことを確認する。あるなら、殺す。
2. それで、同じ事をやって、改善されないなら、rebootする。
3. それで、改善されないなら、Xcodeを削除してから、再インストールする
4. それで、改善されないなら、英語版stackoverflowで、検索してみる。
5. それで、改善されないなら、Xcodeがクラッシュしたとき、Appleへのダンプ付報告レポート画面になるが、ダンプをみて、なにか思いつくことがないか、見る。
6. それで、他にしようがないなら、英語版stackoverflowで、質問する。

くらいですかね。ちなみに、あたりまえですが、当方では、普通に、OS-X=10.10.3/Xcode=6.3.1で、simulatorは起動できてますから、なにか、そちらの環境要因(走行対象app, OS-Xパッチをあてていない,非Macハードウェア)が臭いですが。。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
1から3まで実施しましたがやはりダメでした。これから4以降を実施してみます。
途中気づいたのですが、私のOSは現在Yosemite 10.10なんですね。10.10.3とかではなく。
これが関係していると思いますのでまずそれを解決してみます。これに関してはAppleサポートコミュニティに質問しています。https://discussionsjapan.apple.com/message/100894465
また、環境要因を疑われていますが、私のは買ったばかりの純正のMacbook Airですので心配は無用です。